# PHP XML tags nested in continuing text -> simpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i am working on XML with mostly unknown content.
I am converting it to a very rough HTML output.

but i struggle with this structure in the XML:

```
<wrappingTag>
    text text text
    <formatTag>formatted text</formatTag>
    continued text text text text 
    <formatTag2>much more formatted text</formatTag2>
    continued text text text text 
</wrappingTag>
```

as i use the simpleXML element to get the data, simpleXML returns all the normal text as the value from the "wrappingTag" but without the parts from the "formatTag" values. These come seperate of course.
So putting the text together as it was before seems to be impossible to me.

is there an easy way to solve this in simplexml or do i have to parse that on my own?

thanx

alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM does not suffer from that and you can convert them into each other.

```
$element = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$node = dom_import_simplexml($element);
var_dump($node->nodeValue);
```

DOMElement::$nodeValue is the text content from all descendant text nodes (including cdata).

Another possibility to get the text content from a node is DOMXPath::evaluate().

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//wrappingTag[1])'));
```

Demo: https://eval.in/161109

Comment: Thanks for that tipp, that helps a lot.